# SQL Azure Data Sync service and schema update (Visual Studio Schema Compare)

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, schema-compare, azure-data-sync

I have a local SQL database (database first EF application) and an Azure database which are synced by the azure data sync service.

Now what do I have to do to when I update the local schema of an table? Of course I have to update the schema in the sync service but that is not enough. The schema of the azure database isn't updated by the sync service itself.

Before I used azure data sync I could simply call the sql schema compare from Visual Studio but now there are so many new tables that I don't know what to update and what not.

When I update the azure database manually with the management portal the sync does work. But isn't this also possible via Visual Studio schema compare (or SQL SMMS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you already answered your own question, you said you could do it via VS except that there's too many new tables.

just skip any object that has a DSS prefix to it, those are used by SQL Azure Data Sync Service.

but as you already mentioned, you still have to edit the dataset definition in your Data Sync Service sync group.